# rubber not compiling

Tags: ubuntu, rubber

I have a make file which uses rubber to compile LaTeX files. I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 15.10, and after upgrading, I receive the following error when trying to run rubber on a document. My apologies for the huge stack trace, but my look at it didn't tell me much. It looks like maybe it's a problem with bibtex?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rubber", line 4, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main()(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/cmdline.py", line 331, in __call__
    return self.main(cmdline)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/cmdline.py", line 287, in main
    ret = env.main.make(True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/depend.py", line 164, in make
    ok = self.force_run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/converters/latex.py", line 1288, in force_run
    return self.run(True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/converters/latex.py", line 1310, in run
    if not self.post_compile():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/converters/latex.py", line 1261, in post_compile
    if not mod.post_compile():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/converters/latex.py", line 1526, in post_compile
    return self.pymodule.post_compile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/latex_modules/bibtex.py", line 421, in post_compile
    return biblio.post_compile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/latex_modules/bibtex.py", line 235, in post_compile
    return self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/latex_modules/bibtex.py", line 258, in run
    if self.doc.env.execute(['bibtex', basename], doc, pwd=workdir):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rubber/environment.py", line 226, in execute
    stderr = stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Comment: Apparently `rubber` is not compatible with Python 2.7. Unfortunately the program has been unmaintained for several years.

Comment: Are there any other similar programs?

Comment: You should try `arara`